# Thrift PHP/Java error during ./configuration execution

Tags: thrift

I have boost*-1.69.0-8 installed on my Fedora (as package), gradle binaries 5.6.2

```
➜ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.6.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-09-05 16:13:54 UTC
Revision:     55a5e53d855db8fc7b0e494412fc624051a8e781

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          12.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 12.0.1+12)
OS:           Linux 5.2.13-200.fc30.x86_64 amd64
```

When I run

```
$ ./bootstrap.sh
$ ./configure
```

I get the following errors at the end for **Java**:

```
Java Library:
   Using gradlew ............. : lib/java/gradlew
   Using java ................ : java
   Using javac ............... : javac

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

and **PHP:**

```
PHP Library:
   Using php-config .......... : /usr/bin/php-config
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'thrift_protocol.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/thrift_protocol.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/thrift_protocol.so: undefined symbol: _object_and_properties_init), /usr/lib64/php/modules/thrift_protocol.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/thrift_protocol.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
   Using php version ......... : PHP 7.3.9 (cli) (built: Aug 27 2019 22:52:39) ( NTS )
```

### How do I fix that?

## Full output of ./configure

```
thrift 0.12.0

Building C (GLib) Library .... : yes
Building C# (Mono) Library ... : no
Building C++ Library ......... : yes
Building Common Lisp Library.. : no
Building D Library ........... : no
Building Dart Library ........ : no
Building dotnetcore Library .. : no
Building Erlang Library ...... : no
Building Go Library .......... : yes
Building Haskell Library ..... : no
Building Haxe Library ........ : no
Building Java Library ........ : yes
Building Lua Library ......... : no
Building NodeJS Library ...... : yes
Building Perl Library ........ : no
Building PHP Library ......... : yes
Building Plugin Support ...... : no
Building Python Library ...... : yes
Building Py3 Library ......... : yes
Building Ruby Library ........ : no
Building Rust Library ........ : yes

C++ Library:
   C++ compiler .............. : g++ -std=c++11
   Build TZlibTransport ...... : yes
   Build TNonblockingServer .. : yes
   Build TQTcpServer (Qt4) ... : no
   Build TQTcpServer (Qt5) ... : yes
   C++ compiler version ...... : g++ (GCC) 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)

Go Library:
   Using Go................... : /usr/bin/go
   Using Go version........... : go version go1.12.9 linux/amd64

Java Library:
   Using gradlew ............. : lib/java/gradlew
   Using java ................ : java
   Using javac ............... : javac

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '12.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
   Using Gradle version ...... : 
   Using java version ........ : java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16

NodeJS Library:
   Using NodeJS .............. : /usr/bin/node
   Using NodeJS version....... : v10.15.1

PHP Library:
   Using php-config .......... : /usr/bin/php-config
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'thrift_protocol.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/thrift_protocol.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/thrift_protocol.so: undefined symbol: _object_and_properties_init), /usr/lib64/php/modules/thrift_protocol.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/thrift_protocol.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
   Using php version ......... : PHP 7.3.9 (cli) (built: Aug 27 2019 22:52:39) ( NTS )

Python Library:
   Using Python .............. : /home/dmitry/.pyenv/shims/python
   Using Python version ...... : Python 2.7.16
   Using Python3 ............. : /home/dmitry/.pyenv/shims/python3
   Using Python3 version ..... : Python 3.7.4
   Using trial ............... : /usr/bin/trial

Rust Library:
   Using Cargo................ : /usr/bin/cargo
   Using rustc................ : /usr/bin/rustc
   Using Rust version......... : rustc 1.37.0

If something is missing that you think should be present,
please skim the output of configure to find the missing
component.  Details are present in config.log.
```

Comment: Are you trying to build thrift? Could you provide a link to the tarball/repository you are trying to build?

Comment: @g_bor http://apache-mirror.8birdsvideo.com/thrift/0.12.0/thrift-0.12.0.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle version is too old to recognize java 12. You should be able to fix that by updating gradle to latest release.

I am not sure if that would fix the rest, but it's possible that the different language bindings interact that way.

Comment: I have installed latest binary version of graddle 5.6.2, but it didn't help and inside ./config output I see that gradle version is not used:

   Using Gradle version ...... :

Comment: could you try to upgrade the gradle wrapper in lib/java like this: ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 5.6.2

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see the PHP error here. I will try to reproduce it in a vm later.

Comment: it seems it's using lib/java/gradlew, not my system dependency.

Comment: yes, you could try to upgrade or regenerate the wrapper. For upgrade see the above comment. To regenerate run 'gradle wrapper' in lib/java.